# Create new rows that calculates % change between values based on group in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind

I have a table that I created that is grouped by 3 different methods and shows their corresponding accuracy levels (%) per group as shown below:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   Group [3]
  Group    `LOW CONFIDENCE` `HIGH CONFIDENCE` PERFECT `MEDIUM CONFIDENCE` `NO MATCH` `VERY LOW CONFIDENCE`
  <fct>               <dbl>             <dbl>   <dbl>               <dbl>      <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 First_LV          0.416               0.262   0.138               0.135     0.0489              0.000226
2 JW                0.00496             0.531   0.159               0.234     0.0681              0.00250 
3 LV                0.0894              0.450   0.159               0.217     0.0695              0.0143
```

I would like to create new rows/table that calculates the % change between each group value relative to every field of confidence levels (% change between First_LV and JW, and First_LV and LV and then JW and LV for Low confidence, High confidence, etc...).

I was thinking about about doing something like this but it doesn't seem to get the full picture:

```
percent <- function(x) 100 * c(NA * x[1], diff(x) / head(x, -1))
Percent_change_table <- data.frame(table2[1], t(apply(table2[-1], 1, percent)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combn` to create combination of `Group` values.

```
do.call(rbind, combn(seq(nrow(table2)), 2, function(x) {
  data.frame(combination = paste0(table2$Group[x], collapse = '-'), 
             ((table2[x[1], -1] - table2[x[2], -1])/table2[x[1], -1]) * 100)
}, simplify = FALSE))

#   combination LOW_CONFIDENCE HIGH_CONFIDENCE   PERFECT MEDIUM_CONFIDENCE
#1  First_LV-JW       98.80769      -102.67176 -15.21739        -73.333333
#11 First_LV-LV       78.50962       -71.75573 -15.21739        -60.740741
#2        JW-LV    -1702.41935        15.25424   0.00000          7.264957

#    NO_MATCH VERY_LOW_CONFIDENCE
#1  -39.26380           -1006.195
#11 -42.12679           -6227.434
#2   -2.05580            -472.000
```

**data**

```
table2 <- structure(list(Group = c("First_LV", "JW", "LV"), LOW_CONFIDENCE = c(0.416, 
0.00496, 0.0894), HIGH_CONFIDENCE = c(0.262, 0.531, 0.45), PERFECT = c(0.138, 
0.159, 0.159), MEDIUM_CONFIDENCE = c(0.135, 0.234, 0.217), NO_MATCH = c(0.0489, 
0.0681, 0.0695), VERY_LOW_CONFIDENCE = c(0.000226, 0.0025, 0.0143
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not too familiar with combn - do you mind explaining the logic?

Comment: In this case `combn` creates all combination of row indices in the data. Run `combn(seq(nrow(table2)), 2)` to check the output that you get. We can also pass a function in `combn` that can be run on each of these indices. So `x` in `function(x)` has both the indices for every combination meaning 1, 2 in 1st one, 1, 3 in 2nd and 2, 3 in the 3rd. `x[1]` represents the first one i.e 1 in 1, 2 combination and `x[2]` represents the 2nd one i.e 2 in 1, 2. We use it to subset the dataframe `table2` rows.